# Return value of $.post() call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, return-value

I have a jquery $.post function lik so:

```
$.post('/test',json_data, function(data) {
                                result=data
});
```

this function is actually being used in an validation...So it the return value(data) contains true or false. But this value is not being stored in the variable 'result'. I understand that this is because post makes an asynchronous call and hence it does'nt wait for the response. What I want to ask is, is there some workaround for this? or can this call be made synchronous somehow??

Comment: It is asynchronous, you need to check the response inside the callback function - after `result = data` do the checking there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is considered a bad practice but there is an `async` parameter in [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that you can set to `false` and wait synchronously for a result:

```
var result;
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/test',
  data: json_data,
  async: false,
  success: function(data) {
    result=data;
  },
  dataType: 'application/json'
});
//result available here
```

A more idiomatic, although slightly less convenient in this case, would be to take advantage of callbacks:

```
function validate(okCallback, errorCallback) {
    $.post('/test',json_data, function(data) {
        if(data) {
            okCallback();
        } else {
          errorCallback();
        }
    });
}

validate(
    function() {
        //proceed
    },
    function() {
        //display validation error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thakyou for your answer...but it seems I shall have to use the callback approach afterall. I have tried some approaches but to no avail...could you please help me with the issue I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542224/validation-after-ajax-call). or atleast tell me if the approach I am using is ok...I have this nagging feeling that there might be a better way to do this than what I have described.

Answer (score 2):

Check for validity inside the callback

```
 $.post('/test',json_data, function(data) {
    var result=data;
    if(result === true) {
        // do some ok processing...
        } else {
        // do not ok processing...
        }
});
```